# jquery validation plugin - inline depends on

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Using this popular validate plugin http://jqueryvalidation.org/

You can validate fields just by using class="required". Is there a way to add the "depends" rule inline like the required?

Comment: Short answer: no, you cannot use methods which require parameters or functions, like `depends`, inline.  A crude workaround is PSR's answer which creates a specific custom method for the one field/case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no.

You cannot use methods which require parameters or functions, like `depends`, inline.  Only the subset of rules/methods which can be defined with a `true` can be declared inline with the HTML.

- [General Plugin Guidelines](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference)
- [Application of Rules](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate); there is a `depends` example within the `rules` section.

Answer (score 4):

```
$.validator.addMethod("depends", function(value, element) {
            var id =  $(this).attr('depends-on');
        if($('#id').val() == '')
             return false;
        return true;
  }, "This is  Required");
```

Now you can use `depends`

Comment: I'm not seeing how this can work.  `depends` means it depends on some other field to be required.  Your answer shows that it's only required when itself is empty... that's just the standard `required`.  See `rules` section for explanation of `depends`:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Comment: Yes, looks functional.  However, the OP will have to remember that `depends`, as you've defined it here, is not generic and he'll have to create a separate versions of this for each case.

Comment: I was looking for an inline use that can be generic if possible. Can it be done? :)

Comment: @MarkSteggles you can use this depends in inline

Comment: @PSR - It's not a generic solution though. I would have to create a new method for every input i want to use it on... Can you make it generic? something like: <input type="text" depends-on="#id">

Comment: @MarkSteggles, AFAIK, there is no way to use `depends` inline.  The only inline rules are the ones that can be configured with a boolean.

Comment: @MarkSteggles, to accept this answer is totally your prerogative.  Normally declaring rules "inline" negates the need to declare them within the jQuery... that's the whole point of inline rules.  However, with this answer, you'll also have to define the rule within jQuery before you can use it inline.  And as you've already recognized, it's not generic... you'll have to declare a new method within jQuery every unique time you use it.  So like I said, there really is no way to use the default `depends` method inline.

Comment: @Sparky - I meant your comment is the correct answer :) There really is no convenient way to use depends inline. If you add this as answer i will accept it

Comment: @MarkSteggles, Ok, got it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this helps  or not

```
  password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        },
        confirm_password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5,
            equalTo: "#password"  //depends on other field
            notEqual:"#username"  //depends on other field  
        },
```

if any other validations add a method (see @PSR answer)

Comment: What does this have to do with `depends` method?  See `rules` section for explanation:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/